# Calculating the trace of a 3x3 matrix over the rationals when its determinant is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> I encountered a problem where I had a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with rational numbers entries and it was given that $A^3=2A$ and $A$ could not be the zero matix. I was asked to calculate the trace of the square of $A$, namely $tr(A^2)$.

I could find that the determinant $\det(A)=0$ because otherwise it had to be $\sqrt8$ or $-\sqrt8$. This comes from $\det(A)^3=8\det(A)$. Since $\sqrt8$ is not rational the determinant has to be $0$. Is there a way to express $tr(A^2)$ in terms of $\det(A)$?

Comment: How much do you know about eigenvalues and matrix diagonalization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If $A^3=2A$, then its characteristic polynomial is $x^3-2x$.

Indeed, $x^3-2x=x(x^2-2)$ is a decomposition into irreducibles in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Now, the minimal polynomial of $A$ cannot be $x$ because $A\ne0$ or $x^2-2$ because then $\det(A)^2=8$, which cannot happen over $\mathbb Q$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial is $x^3-2x$ and so coincides with the characteristic polynomial.

> The characteristic polynomial of a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ is
> $$
> x^3 - tr(A) x^2 + \frac{tr(A)^2 - tr(A^2)}{2}x - \det(A)
> $$

See [characteristic polynomial in terms of trace and determinant for 4x4 matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420308/characteristic-polynomial-in-terms-of-trace-and-determinant-for-4x4-matrices).

Comparing coefficients, we get
$tr(A)=0$ and so $tr(A^2)=4$.

Comment: Going from $A^3 = 2A$ to "its characteristic polynomial is $x^3 - 2x$" is non-trivial. In particular, you need to make use of the fact that $A$ is a matrix with rational entries and that $A$ is not the zero matrix

Comment: @BenGrossmann, indeed. See my edited answer. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is the first time I heared about minimal polinomials(I am new to linear algebra). I was wondering if there could arise a contradiction if the coeficient of the minimal polynomial is not 1 like the minimal polynomial to be 3x^2+1. Wouldn't there be a contradiction when comparing coeficients to the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @Shthephathord23, both the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial are monic by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Experiment with
$$
A = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

For example, find $A^3$ and compare that with $2A$

Also find $A^2$    and its trace